# I need to make a two subscribe await

Tags: angular

I am obtaining the lists by the id of the projects but now to obtain the cards I need to obtain the id of the lists, but for that I need to do an await if you could guide me on how the code would be

```
this.route.paramMap.pipe(
  map((param: ParamMap) => {
    // @ts-ignore
    return param.params.id;
  })
).subscribe(prodId => {
  this.id = prodId;
  console.log("Titulo de Proyecto", prodId)
  this.API.getNombreProyecto(this.id).subscribe(prod => {
    this.project = prod;
  });

  
});

this.API.getListas(this.id)
.subscribe((data: Customer[]) => {
  console.log('Obtener Listas:::', data);
  this.customersx = data;
  console.log('Obtener Listas:::',this.customersx);
  
}); 


this.API.getCards(this.id)

.subscribe((data: CustomerCards[]) => {
  this.defaults.id = this.id;
  console.log('Obtener Listas:::', data);
  this.customersy = data;
  console.log('Obtener Listas:::',this.customersy);
  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I exactly didn't get what you really want to achieve, as description posted by you seems not easily understandable.

But I will try to give you an idea, how can you do that. Check the below code.

```
 this.route.paramMap
  .pipe(
    switchMap((param: ParamMap) => {
      this.id = param.params.id;
      return forkJoin([
          this.API.getNombreProyecto(this.id),
          this.API.getListas(this.id),
          this.API.getCards(this.id)
      ]);
    })
  )
  .subscribe(([project, customersx, data])=>{
    this.project = project;
    this.customersx = customersx;
    this.customersy = data;
  })
```

Now by referencing the above code, you can try to modify your code to make it in the order you want.

Comment: Thank you very much, but I will leave you a brief explanation of the subject of the project, I am doing a scrumboard, FIRST IN THE FIRST CODE I AM BRINGING GetListas through the project id and thanks to that it invokes the lists according to the project id, now to obtain el getCards I need the ID of the lists but every time I want to obtain it, it comes out undefined what I want is to link the lists and cards so that the cards work so what they explained to me is that I can await